# How can I count data in a single table, and combine with data from multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

**users** - with an id, client_id and username

**maindata** - with a client_id, usernames, and descriptions (many usernames for each client_id) and the main data that I need to COUNT.

**clients** - with a client_id and client_name (not a username)

I need to grab the data from maindata which has fields of:

```
usernames, client_id, and description
```

and see for all records in maindata: **how many appear with the same username, client_id and description**.

Once I get the count, I need to grab the user_id associated with that username from maindata.

I feel like I could do this in one SQL call, but for now I am running a for loop after getting a list of all users (because that has the usernames and client_id), but not sure I need to, I may be able to include those in my query.

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
    users = cur.fetchall()
    for u in users:
        user = u[2]
        client_id = u[1]
        cur.execute("SELECT clients.name,maindata.client_id,maindata.username,users.id,COUNT(*) "
                    "FROM maindata CROSS JOIN users "
                    "INNER JOIN clients ON maindata.client_id=clients.id "
                    "WHERE description LIKE '%teal%' "
                    "AND maindata.username='{}' AND maindata.client_id='{}' ".format(user,client_id)) #This will return the client and the number of countableDatas
        totalCountswithIDs = cur.fetchall()
```

So the end result should be return value of:

- Client Name (found in clients)
- Client ID (found in maindata)
- Username (found in maindata)
- User ID (found in users)
- Count (for all combinations of Client ID + Username + specified description)

Am I far off? Thank you for any help in advance!

Sample data:

```
maindata:
id, client_id, username, description
(1, '1', 'rusty', 'blue'),
(2, '2', 'john', 'yellow brick road'),
(3, '3', 'helen', 'teal'),
(4, '3', 'helen', 'teal'),
(5, '3', 'helen', 'teal'),

users:
id, client_id, username
(1743, 2, 'john'),
(1742, 3, 'helen'),
(1189, 1, 'rusty'),

clients:
id, name
(1, 'Apple'),
(2, 'Amazon'),
(3, 'Google'),
```

The results from this would be:

- Apple, 1, rusty, 1189, 1
- Amazon, 2, john, 1743, 1
- Google, 3, helen, 1742, 3

The last one has 3 because there are 3 that match my LIKE search of "teal", as an example.

Comment: Without the sample data and expected output it's not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I've just appended sample data

Comment: Try This Demo http://rextester.com/ZWIC63437

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you question correctly this would be one approach

```
with users as (
Select 1743 id, 2 client_id ,'john' username UNION ALL
Select 1742 id, 3 client_id ,'helen' username UNION ALL
Select 1189 id, 1 client_id ,'rusty' username 
)
,
maindata as
(
SELECT 1 id , '1' client_id, 'apple' username , 1520900834 DontKnown, 'blue'     description UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '2', 'admin', 1520901427, 'yellow brick road' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '3', 'helen', 1520902247, 'teal' UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '3', 'helen', 1520902243, 'teal' UNION ALL
SELECT 5, '3', 'helen', 15202022347, 'teal'
),
clients as
(Select 1 client_id ,'Apple' name union all
Select 2,'Amazon' UNION ALL
Select 3,'Google'
) --Apple, 1, rusty, 1189, 1 Amazon, 2, john, 1743, 1 Google, 3, helen,     1742, 3
select distinct c.name,c.client_id,u.username,u.id,m.cnt_maindata
FROM 
(
Select *,count(*) OVER(PARTITION BY client_id,description) cnt_maindata from     maindata
) m
JOIN users u on m.client_id=u.client_id
JOIN clients c on c.client_id=m.client_id
```

Output:

```
name    client_id   username    id  cnt_maindata
Amazon  2           john        1743    1
Apple   1           rusty       1189    1
Google  3           helen       1742    3
```

Comment: Hi fact - What does the Select 1, id, 100 mean? Are those sample ids?

Comment: I just created sample data, do you have sample data? Basically you answer will be the Select statement only

Comment: I've just appended sample data

Comment: Can you provide the output as well also in the sample data you mentioned 4 columns of maindata but you have extra value

Comment: Yup just added! Thank you in advance

Comment: Cleaned up :) .

Comment: Your out put is not clear, please make it well formatted

Comment: Looking at your sample it appears to me that grouping on the client_id is sufficient .If you want to group just on client_id then you can remove the description from "PARTITION BY client_id,description"

Comment: @Fact do I need to run calls first to grab all of this data? For instance, I have the data as sample data but ideally I wouldn't want to hardcode it in, would I need to do a select * from maindata then do as you did? It's unclear which bits of your code are meant to be hardcoded and which can be reused with new data.

Comment: You may run the select statement only, if the sample data table names and column names matches your original table name and columns there should be no problem. There's no hard coding in the code, I was mentioning that to get the count from the maindata table you can group only on the client_id.